# Copy the behavior of one class to another class

Tags: c#, wpf

Suppose I have the following class

```
class A : Canvas
{
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //the behaviour
    }
}
```

And another class that contains first as a property

```
class B : Canvas
{
    private readonly A _a;

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //the same behaviour
    }
}
```

How to achieve the same behaviour without duplicate code? If I use base.OnMouseDown(), I get behaviour of Canvas which makes sense, but I need the behaviour of decorated class as I'm implementing **Decorator pattern** here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create some base class that inherits `Canvas` and then inherit it by `A` and `B`:

```
class CommonClass : Canvas
{
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //some behavior
    }

    //other common implementation for derived classes
}

class A : CommonClass 
{
    // implementation specific to "A" and overrides
}

class B : CommonClass 
{
    // implementation specific to "B" and overrides
}
```

As a result you will get one same method `OnMouseDown()` with same behavior in `A` and `B`.